# Merging polynomials together

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-combinatorics, resultant

Given the (monic) polynomials $P$ and $Q$, we can split them over an appropriate field into linear factors to write $P(x)=(x-a_1)\dotsb(x-a_m)$ and $Q(x)=(x-b_1)\dotsb(x-b_n)$, and then form the polynomial
$$ P(x-b_1)\dotsb P(x-b_n) = Q(x-a_1)\dotsb Q(x-a_m) . $$
Is there any standard notation or name for this new polynomial? Have its properties been studied?

Comment: In other words, please provide some context for why you are asking about this. I am not trying to be dismissive in my previous comment, but trying to point out that it will be helpful in answering your question if you can provide us with some motivation.

Comment: @Morgan Rodgers: I believe that this is a *very* interesting polynomial because it encodes the sumset $A+B$ (defined as a set of all possible sums $a+b$ with $a\in A$ and $b\in B$). Cards on the table, I want to say something non-trivial in the situation where $P=Q$ divides this new polynomial.

Comment: So this new polynomial will just equal $\prod_{i,j}(x-(a_{i}+b_{j}))$, correct? If $P=Q$, $\prod_{i,j}(x-(a_{i}+a_{j}))$, and $P(x)$ will divide this polynomial if and only if $\{a_{1}, \ldots, a_{m}\} \subseteq \{a_{i}+a_{j} \ : \ 1 \leq i,j \leq m\}$ (we need to consider both of these as multisets if the $a_{i}$ are not distinct).

Comment: @MorganRodgers: right.

Comment: In that case I am adding the `algebraic-combinatorics` tag, which will hopefully the kind of interest you may be looking for. Are there specific things you are hoping to learn about this polynomial (other than if it already has a name)? This chapter by Terrence Tao doesn't mention it specifically, but does talk about polynomial methods applied to sum sets: https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/additive-combinatorics/algebraic-methods/E5EEB6E901D0345D5DA470F1644CD92B (not a pdf, just including link for reference)

Comment: @MorganRodgers: for instance, what are alternative ways to define the polynomial in question without factoring the original $P$ and $Q$ (in terms of their coefficients, or maybe the derivatives)?

Answer (score 1):

I am going to give an answer to the question asked in the comments

> What are alternative ways to define the polynomial in question without factoring the original P and Q

Let $T_x(y)=Q(x-y)$ be understood as a polynomial in $F[x][y]$, where $F$ is a field. I claim that

> The resultant $\operatorname{Res}(P(y),T_x(y),y)$ with respect to $y$ is equal to $\prod_{i=1}^mQ(x-a_i)$.

Proof. Let $R$ be an integral domain and $f$ and $g$ monic polynomials in $R[y]$ of degrees $m$ and $n$, and with roots $\lambda_i$ and $\mu_j$ in any algebraically closed field containing $R$, respectively. Their resultant with respect to $y$ is
$$\operatorname{Res}(f,g,y)=\prod_{i=1}^m g(\lambda_i)=(-1)^{mn}\prod_{j=1}^n f(\mu_j).$$
Now apply the above for $f(y):=P(y)$ and $g(y):=T_x(y)=Q(x-y)$. The first equality gives
$$\operatorname{Res}(P(y),T_x(y),y)=\prod_{i=1}^m T_x(a_i)=\prod_{i=1}^mQ(x-a_i).$$

> Corollary. The polynomial $\prod_{j=1}^nP(x-b_j)=\prod_{i=1}^mQ(x-a_i)$ can be computed without factoring $P$ or $Q$.

Proof. Compute the Sylvester determinant for $P(y)$ and $Q(x-y)$ with respect to $y$ (for the relevant definitions see e.g. the wiki articles for [Resultant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant) or [Sylvester matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_matrix)).

Comment: Thank you. Does this provide any insight into when $P$ divides the polynomial in question?